# Rocky linux wireguard firewalld MASQUERADE in custom zone

Tags: firewalld, wireguard

I'm trying to set up a masquerade for wireguard. To open it using such a code that I found

**wg0.conf**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 2CSTiZ0l30qQZ6IZfnfvpvVMYlLGxAMLHTK8ZF8qpHs=
Address = 172.16.100.1
ListenPort = 51820

PostUp = firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade; firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i wg0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT; firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE; firewall-cmd --add-port=51820/udp

PostDown = firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-masquerade; firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i wg0 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT; firewall-cmd --direct --remove-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE; firewall-cmd --remove-port=51820/udp
```

This solution works, but I would also like to add a firewall for the interface `wg0`

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --change-zone=wg0 --zone=work
firewall-cmd --reload
```

If I do this, then I only have access to the local network, but the Internet disappears
Tried like this

```
firewall-cmd --zone=work --add-masquerade;
firewall-cmd --reload
```

But it doesn't work. As soon as the `wg0` interface enters the `work` zone, the Internet on wireguard clients disappears and it is not clear how to fix it. Previous versions of the red hat did not have such problems.

Comment: Видимо фвд нынче использует нфтаблес и твои правила иптаблес ему пабрабану. Check nft rules